# Who's to blame?! (aka newer chat message appears before older chat messsage)

Tags: support, bug, chat

So, I just saw this in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta):

> [image]

The second message was posted **before** the first, yet appears after that message.

Checking the ID of the messages, the ID of the first (`!!/blame`) is [5935908](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5935908#5935908), while the ID of the reply is [5935909](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5935909#5935909), so no trick as far as I can see. Also no edits.

What black magic is involved here?

From responses here and in chat, looks like it affects only part of the users, while others see the messages in the correct order. So I guess it's something with the cache servers.

Comment: Time sync between the API server has drifted ?

Comment: @Tensibai but it never happened before, with thousands upon thousands of messages.

Comment: Well, it's obviously Mithrandir's fault

Comment: I'm a wizard. There will be magic. Especially with a Sauron avatar.

Comment: @Stijn I reloaded several times before posting. I also tried now in private/Incognito modes, and with different browsers. All the same.

Comment: This happened [again](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ISaXv.png) over in Charcoal HQ, again with me and Smokey.

Comment: @Mithrandir I see it in the right order :)

Comment: This tends to happen to me when I'm on a slower computer; maybe that's it?

Comment: @Art nope. Got fast connection, tried now from home too, different ISP, still the same. Maybe related to location, really no idea.

Comment: I see it in the wrong order, as the OP sees it. This happened with my bot before: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33612787#33612787. It looked normal at the time, but now it's reversed.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not a client-side issue. [This is part of the results I get from the ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD2OH.png). The two messages are in the wrong order, assuming the script blindly appends messages in the order received. Note that `time_stamps` is identical for both, so maybe it should order by id, not timestamp (or both).